# Apache Nutch: LinkConent inlink and from url

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch, pagerank

I am using apache nutch to crawl some websites upto 6 levels deep. I am dumping the link content to my current working directory. The link content contains data in the following format:

```
www.abc.com/help Inlink:
  fromUrl: www.abc.com anchor: Help
  fromUrl: www.xyz.com anchor: abc help
```

My question with respect to nutch is, if nutch is able to generate the above data, should'nt the same lincontent file contain www.abc.com and its Inlink: information (similarly information about www.xyz.com) considering it has information about abc.com/help, it would have analyzed from www.abc.com and www.xyz.com. However I dont find the fromUrls having their inlink information in some cases. Why would this be? Am i missing something here?

Comment: How can you get the Inlink & outlinks in this format? can you share the command for that?

Answer (score 1):

Nutch by default adds outlinks to the `linkdb` only for different domains to reduce the size of the link database. In order to populate all inlinks, both `db.ignore.internal.links` and `linkdb.ignore.external.links` have to be set to `false` in `nutch-default.xml` or overriden in `nutch-site.xml`.